# VS 2008 solution building

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, projects-and-solutions

I have two projects, When i select 'Build Solution' for p1, it does nothing. That is I can build projects of p1, but not the solution. The same 'Build Solution' option works fine for p2?

:( . Is there any option should i change on p1 to enable build?

Comment: Well, you did a pretty poor job on the question.  Bad tagging, confused project/solution terminology, no clear explanation of bad behavior vs expected.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, a solution build builds various projects in your solution and compiles them into dll assemblies.

There is no dll assembly for a solution. A solution is a group of projects that build either separately or together.

To manage which projects build and which to not, use the Solution Configurations dropdown in the top toolstrip. That lets you define which projects build and which are ignored when you click "Build Solution".